# ¿Como definir a valor como único mediante la restricción CHECK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con campos de PROSPECTOS como son nombre, dirección, teléfono etc...

Uno de los campos es el CURP y quiero que esta columna contenga datos únicos.
El problema surge en que los registros de prospectos en esta tabla son personas físicas y morales, por lo que no todos tienen CURP, asi que la restricción UNIQUE no me funciona por que aunque acepta valores null, solo acepta un valor null en toda la columna.

Se me ocurre que podría definir una condición con la restricción CHECK pero no e encontrado el como comparar con los demás registros de la tabla, solo con el registro que se introduce.

Es posible generar esta validación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es relativamente sencillo de lograr usando índices filtrados:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Curp ON dbo.Prospectos(Curp) WHERE Curp IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Me da la impresión que no se puede. Lo que sí, puedes hacer un TRIGGER que valide el dato, algo como esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROSPECTOS_INSERT ON PROSPECTOS FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @errmsg     VARCHAR(255)

    IF UPDATE(CURP)
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM INSERTED P
                INNER JOIN PROSPECTOS I
                    ON I.CURP = I.CURP
                WHERE   P.CURP IS NOT NULL
            )
        BEGIN

            SELECT  @errmsg = 'Alguno de los prospectos insertados tiene un CURP que ya existe'
            GOTO ERROR

        END

    END
    RETURN

ERROR:
    RAISERROR( @errmsg, 16, 1)

END
```

- CURP debiera ser índice para no "matar" los inserts/updates
- En teoria este ejemplo debiera funcionar también en el caso del UPDATE

Comment: Ah, pero sí se puede, con un índice como mostré en mi respuesta